# changing select/option generic text through inputs above it

Tags: javascript, forms

I'm aiming to have the text input from a textfield replace the generic options on a select/option drop-down. what im doing now isn't working, and shows up as **undefined**.
Here is my markup: (please include a vanilla javascript option please)
HTML:

```
<input id="name1" type="text" placeholder="name here" onKeyUp="return change1(this)">
<input id="name2" type="text" placeholder="name here" onKeyUp="return change2(this)">
```

etc.

```
<h4>Choose person:</h4>
<select id="select1">
<option id="pers1" value="1">person</option>
<option id="pers2" value="2">person</option>
```

..also several of these

Javascript:

```
function change1(input){
 document.getElementById("pers1").text =
 input.text; }
function change2(input){
 document.getElementById("pers2").text =
 input.text; }
```

etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First to answer your question, you were getting `undefined` because you were using `input.text`. This can be achieved using the `.value` property. Read up more about getting value of input text boxes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11563667/1179865).
Also you can achieve this with a single function, simply by tweaking the id on your option elements.

the function:

```
function change1(e) {
    document.getElementById("pers_" + e.id).text = document.getElementById(e.id).value;
}
```

the HTML:

```
<input id="name1" type="text" placeholder="name1 here" onKeyUp="return change1(this)">
<input id="name2" type="text" placeholder="name2 here" onKeyUp="return change1(this)">
<select id="select1">
    <option id="pers_name1" value="1">person1</option>
    <option id="pers_name2" value="2">person2</option>
</select>
```

[Here is a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2bYG5/)

Answer (score 2):

```
<script>
    function change1(input){
        document.getElementById("pers1").text = input.value; 
    }
    function change2(input){
        document.getElementById("pers2").text = input.value; 
    } 
</script>
<h4>Choose person:</h4>
<select id="select1">
    <option id="pers1" value="1">person</option>
    <option id="pers2" value="2">person</option>
</select>
<hr>
<input id="name1" type="text" placeholder="name here" onKeyUp="change1(this)">
<input id="name2" type="text" placeholder="name here" onKeyUp="change2(this)">
```